# Nginx skipping location

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx

I have nginx in front of Apache serving static content. However, I want nginx to serve a page and not go to apache.

```
...
server {
location /nginx_status {
stub_status on;
}
}
include "/etc/nginx/vhosts/*";
```

However, when I try and access it IP/nginx_status I get a 404 page on Apache.

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.4.1
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-pcre=/usr/local/src/publicnginx/pcre-8.32 --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-http_realip_module --with-http_ssl_module --http-client-body-temp-path=/tmp/nginx_client --http-proxy-temp-path=/tmp/nginx_proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/tmp/nginx_fastcgi --with-http_stub_status_module
```

Comment: Your question cannot be answered without your full server block config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

I needed to add a listen block under the server.